# How to efficiently transpose rows into columns in Vim?

Tags: perl, vim

I have a data file like the following:

```
----------------------------
a b c d e .............
A B C D E .............
----------------------------
```

But I want it to be in the following format:

```
----------------------------
a A
b B
c C
d D
e E
...
...
----------------------------
```

What is the quickest way to do the transformation in Vim or Perl?

Comment: The [transpose plugin](https://github.com/salsifis/vim-transpose) can do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically `:.s/ /`<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>`/g`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`jma:.s/ /`<kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>`/g`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd>`'axgg$p'adG` will do the trick. :)

OK, let's break that down:

1. `:.s/ /`<kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>`/g`<kbd>Enter</kbd>: On the current line (`.`), substitute (`s`) spaces (`/ /`) with a space followed by a carriage return (<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>`/`), in all positions (`g`). The cursor should now be on the last letter's line (`e` in the example).
2. `j`: Go one line down (to `A B C D E`).
3. `ma`: Set mark `a` to the current position... because we want to refer to this position later.
4. `:.s/ /`<kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>`/g`<kbd>Enter</kbd>: Do the same substitution as above, but without the <kbd>Space</kbd>. The cursor should now be on the last letter's line (`E` in the example).
5. <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd>`'a`: Select from the current cursor position (`E`) to mark `a` (that we set in step 3 above), using the block select.
6. `x`: Cut the selection (into the `"` register).
7. `gg`: Move the cursor to the first line.
8. `$`: Move the cursor to the end of the line.
9. `p`: Paste the previously cut text after the cursor position.
10. `'a`: Move the cursor to the `a` mark (set in step 3).
11. `dG`: Delete everything (the empty lines left at the bottom) from the cursor position to the end of the file.

P.S. I was hoping to learn about a "built-in" solution, but until such time...

Answer (score 4):

Simple re-map of the columns:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = map [ split ], <>;  # split each line on whitespace and store in array
for (0 .. $#{$a[0]}) {      # for each such array element
    printf "%s %s\n", $a[0]->[$_], $a[1]->[$_];   # print elements in order
}
```

**Usage:**

```
perl script.pl input.txt
```

Comment: It would be nice to directly transform the data file in VIM. Can this be rewritten to use in VIM?

Comment: @stonebird Not by me. But why would you want to, when you can do it cleanly in perl?

Comment: You can use Perl scripts inside Vim. Take a look at `:help :perl`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the cursor is on the first of the two lines, I would use
the command

```
:s/ /\r/g|+&&|'[-;1,g/^/''+m.|-j
```